# Foo.class.getPackage().getImplementationVersion() returns null when called from Oracle

Tags: oracle, oracle11g, java-6

I'm running into a problem trying to get some version information from a jar when it is called from my oracle 11g stored procedure.

I have a helper method in a class contained in the jar:

```
public class Version {
    public static String getVersion() {
        return Version.class.getPackage().getImplementationVersion();
    }
}
```

When I call this from java:
    Version.getVersion();

It returns the correct version of the jar

When I load this jar using the loadjava command and call this from oracle:

```
create function version_test return varchar2
as language java
name 'com.foo.Version.getVersion() return java.lang.String';

select
version_test
from dual;
```

It returns null.

Do any of you guys know what might be going on and how I could get the version once loaded into oracle?